# Is the Gauss Divergence theorem applicable when the Divergence of a vector field is a dirac delta function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, dirac-delta, divergence-theorem

(This question is motivated by electrostatics)

In electrostatics one comes across discontinuous vector fields all the time, for example, the vector field $ \vec E=\frac{\vec r}{r^3} $ which has a missing point discontinuity at $\vec r=0$, whose divergence $\nabla\cdot \vec E$ is the dirac delta distribution (to be precise, $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E=4\pi\delta(\vec r)$, using test functions and so on). It is not clear to me how one can assert that the volume integral of this dirac delta distribution, $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E$, is equal to the surface integral of the field, which is discontinuous.

Yet, physics textbooks still apply the Gauss Divergence theorem, to say that $\iiint_{V}\nabla\cdot\vec E d\tau=\iint_{S}\vec E\cdot\hat ndS$, where V contains the singularity $\vec r =0$, but don't explain *why* one is allowed to do this, when the vector field is clearly discontinuous in the domain in which the integral is being done. Alas, the integral $\iint_{S}\vec E \cdot \hat n dS= \iint_S\frac{\hat r \cdot \hat n dS}{r^2}$ comes out to be $4\pi$, but my question still holds.

Now, I am aware that the result *for this case* comes out to be exactly the same, $4\pi$, through different calculations, but is this a coincicende? More precicely, given a vector field $\vec E$ which is defined , continuous and differentiable everywhere except at $\vec r=0$, whose divergence $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E$ comes out to be the dirac delta distribution, can we apply gauss divergence theorem in such a case (case where we include the origin)?

Comment: The Gauss theorem does not hold and that's exactly the reason why physicists put the factor $4\pi$ in front of the delta function which at first glance seems rather arbitrary. It is a fix that works.

Comment: When $\vec{E}$ is a vector distribution which doesn't have a singularity on $S$ then the Gauss divergence theorem works.

Comment: "doesn't have a singularity on $S$" should rather be "is smooth on $S$"

Comment: Yes, it's fudgtastic Physics-Maths but if you made everything smooth so its all volume functions instead of things like point charges, then because dv goes to zero much faster than 1/r goes to infinity, it all works out. (Sigh of relief...)

Comment: @SimonGoater. It's possible to give a rigorous meaning of the Gauss divergence theorem when the singular support of $\nabla\cdot\vec{E}$ is disjoint from the boundary of the region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$, the distribution $\nabla \cdot \vec E$, for $\vec E=\frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ satisfies

$$\begin{align}
\langle \nabla \cdot \vec E,\phi\rangle &=-\sum_{i=1}^3 \langle E_i, \partial_i \phi \rangle\\\\
&=-\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}\vec E\cdot \nabla \phi\, d^3r\tag1\\\\
&=-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R^3}\setminus \{\vec r||\vec r|<\varepsilon\}}\vec E\cdot \nabla \phi\, d^3r\tag2\\\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \phi(\vec r)\,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi \tag3\\\\
&=4\pi \phi(0)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, in distribution $\nabla \cdot \vec E=4\pi \delta(\vec r)$.

**NOTES:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we exclude the ball $|\vec r|<\varepsilon$ from the integral over $\mathbb{R^3}$ and take the limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we integrate by parts using $\nabla \cdot (\phi \vec E)=\vec E\cdot \nabla \phi+\phi\nabla \cdot \vec E$, the Divergence Theorem, which applies to the region $\mathbb{R^3}\setminus \{\vec r||\vec r|<\varepsilon\}$, and exploited the fact that $\nabla \cdot \vec E=0$ for $\vec r\ne0$.

Comment: I really like this derivation / proof. step 2 $\to$ 3 is ingenious in my opinion. I suppose my takeaway message is in general, integrals involving the dirac delta are to be evaluated by excluding the ball of $\epsilon$ and applying the limit, which I suppose naturally allows for the divergence theorem to hold?

Comment: Well, not quite.  Remember that distributions are linear functionals, not integrals.  The term $\nabla \cdot \frac{\vec r}{r^3}$ is a distribution and the term on the left-hand side of the equation preceding $(1)$ is not an integral.  We used the definition of the derivative of a distribution to arrive at $(1)$, which is an integral.

Comment: You are showing that $\nabla\cdot\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} = \delta$ but the main question is whether and why the Gauss divergence theorem is applicable when the vector field is not continuous inside the region.

Comment: @md2perpe The OP seemed satisfied.  And a couple of others found the post useful.  Moreover, I provided the correct interpretation of the divergence of the electric field from a point charge.  So all is good.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded region and $\mathbf{F}$ be a distribution-valued vector field which is $C^\infty$ on $\partial\Omega$. Then the product $(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F})\chi_\Omega,$ where $\chi_\Omega$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $\Omega,$ is defined as a distribution. Since this product has compact support (as $\Omega$ is bounded) the action of it on $\mathbf{1},$ the function that has value $1$ everywhere, is defined: $\langle (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F})\chi_\Omega, \mathbf{1} \rangle.$
If $\mathbf{F}$ is smooth, this is exactly $\int_\Omega (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}) \, dV,$ where $V$ is the volume measure of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Now, by the product law,
$
(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F})\chi_\Omega
= \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{F}\,\chi_\Omega)
- \mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla\chi_\Omega
,
$
so
$$
\langle (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F})\chi_\Omega, \mathbf{1} \rangle
= \langle \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{F}\,\chi_\Omega), \mathbf{1} \rangle
- \langle \mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla\chi_\Omega, \mathbf{1} \rangle
.
$$
Here the first term on the right hand side vanishes since, by definition of derivatives of distributions, the derivative is moved to the test function, where here is $\mathbf{1},$ and $\nabla\mathbf{1}=0.$ Thus we have
$$
\langle (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F})\chi_\Omega, \mathbf{1} \rangle
= - \langle \mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla\chi_\Omega, \mathbf{1} \rangle
.
$$
But $\nabla\chi_\Omega$ only has support on $\partial\Omega$ since $\chi_\Omega$ is constant on both the interior and the exterior of $\Omega$ so the gradient vanishes there. Also, the gradient points in the direction in which the function grows fastest, which is into $\Omega,$ i.e. in the negative direction of the normal. We can therefore identify the right hand side as $\oint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS,$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is the outwards pointing normal and $S$ is the surface measure.

Thus, writing $\int_\Omega (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}) \, dV$ for $\langle (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F})\chi_\Omega, \mathbf{1} \rangle$ and $\oint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS$ for $\langle \mathbf{F}\cdot(-\nabla\chi_\Omega), \mathbf{1} \rangle$ we have
$$
\int_\Omega (\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}) \, dV = \oint_{\partial\Omega} \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS
$$
also for distribution-valued vector fields under some assumptions.